# Change Bootstrap popover title when ToolTip attribute exists

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on my page like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success help-target" rel="popover" data-content="This is the help contnet" data-placement="left" tooltip="Click to submit this form">Submit Review to AMR<button>
```

I also have some JavaScript on my page like this:

```
function showHelp() {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $('[rel=popover]').popover({ 'trigger': 'manual', 'title': function () { return 'Help'; } });
    $('[rel=popover]').popover('show');
}
```

I've tried setting the "title" of my popover in two different ways, one is in the javascript code using the 'title' option and the other uses the data-title attribute on the HTML element. However, what is actually showing up in the title of my popover is the content of the "tooltip" attribute on the button element.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to override that. I need the tooltip attribute on the element because I want that to show up when a user hovers over the element.

Is there an easy way to override the title that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 0):

Was something like the following what you had in mind? This example in jsbin uses bootstrap 2.3.2.

http://jsbin.com/EMiXiv/2

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success help-target" 
data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-toggle="popover" 
data-content="This is the help content" 
data-placement="left">Submit Review to AMR</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.help-target').popover({ 'title': 'Popover Title'});  
$('.help-target').tooltip({ 'title': 'tooltip message', 'placement': 'top'});
```

Comment: Tried this, but it had no effect.

Comment: @Scott - the jsbin works, so having more details about your particular page might have been useful.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't accurately reflect my problem. The button also has a "tooltip" attribute with some text in it so that when a user overs over it, they see the standard HTML tooltip (it's not using the Bootstrap tooltip plugin for those). No matter what I try, the text in the "title" attribute is always used for the title of the popover.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me since I want all visible popovers to have the same title:

```
function showHelp() {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $('[rel=popover]').popover({ 'trigger': 'manual', 'title': function () { return 'Help'; } });
    $('[rel=popover]').popover('show');
    $('.popover-title').text('Help');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('[title]').attr("data-rel", "tooltip");
    $("[data-rel='tooltip']")
        .attr("data-placement", "top")
        .attr("data-content", function() {
            return $(this).attr("title")
        })
        .removeAttr('title');


    var showPopover = function() {
        $(this).popover('show');
    };
    var hidePopover = function() {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    };
    $("[data-rel='tooltip']").popover({
        trigger: 'manual'
    }).click(showPopover).hover(showPopover, hidePopover);

});
```

and simple ***HTML***

What is this